# Getting the list associations from has_many :through with a nested has_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, has-many-through, nomethoderror

Simple problem I can't figure out.

How do you get a list of associated items that are associated with a list of another type of item.  For example a `Clinician` `has_many` `patients` through `care_group_assignments` and `patients` `has_many` `assessments`.  I want a list of `patients` to give me a list of all of their `assessments`. `@patients` gives me the list of `patients`; how do I get their lists of `assessments`? I want `@assessments` to be a list of all of the `assessments` associated with all of the `patients` associated with a given `clinician`.

I have a has_many :through relationship between 'Clinician', and 'Patient' with a joined model 'CareGroupAssignment'.

**clinician.rb** (simplified)

```
class Clinician < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :patients ,:through=> :care_group_assignments
    has_many :care_group_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :assessments, :through => :patients

    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user,  :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**patient.rb**

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :clinicians ,:through=> :care_group_assignments
    has_many :care_group_assignments

    has_many :assessments, dependent: :destroy

    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user,  :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**care_group_assignments.rb**

```
class CareGroupAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :clinician
    belongs_to :patient
end
```

I tried using answers from [4720492](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720492/nested-has-many-through-in-rails-3), [9408931](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408931/has-many-through-with-has-and-belongs-to-many-in-rails), and [15256541](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256541/rails-associations-has-many-through).

I am trying to get the list in the ClinicianController:

```
def show
  @clinician = Clinician.find_by(id: params["id"])
  @patients = @clinician.patients
  @assessments = @patients.assessments.order("created_at desc")
end
```

`current_clinician` is defined in my `ApplicationController` as:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user
  before_action :require_user
  helper_method :current_clinician
  before_action :require_clinician

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by!(auth_token: cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  end

  def require_user
    if current_user.nil?
      redirect_to new_session_path
    end
  end

  def current_clinician
    current_user.clinician
  end

  def require_clinician
    if current_clinician.nil?
      redirect_to new_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

Right now I get a `NoMethodError in CliniciansController#show`,

> undefined method `assessments' for #Patient:.....

Rails 4.1.8, ruby 2.2.1p85, PostgreSQL

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe what do you want to show in `@esas_assessments = @patients.assessments.order("created_at desc")`?

Comment: I want a list of `patients` to give me a list of all of their `assessments`. `@patients` gives me the list of patients; how do I get their lists of `assessments`?  I want `@assessments` to be a list of all of the `assessments` associated with all of the `patients` associated with a given `clinician`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `@clinician.assessments`? You should be able to get the results you want through the magic of AR and join tables!

Comment: that worked! thanks. can't believe it was that simple

Comment: No problem! For future reference, when you have has_many/belongs_to methods, they become part of the model's callable methods. For example, for any clinician you can call the following methods in addition to the clinician's attributes: clinician.patients, clinician.care_group_assignments, clinician.assessments, and clinician.user. Active Record does all the heavy lifting (generating the SQL queries) for you!

Answer (score 0):

According your `Patient` model, `Patient` `has_many` assessments but in action `show` you use:

```
@assessments = @patients.assessments.order("created_at desc")
```

Where `@patients` - list of items of the model `Patient`.

You should refactor you logic there.

Comment: How do you recommend I refactor my logic?  I want a list of items to give me a list of all of their sub-items.  `@patients` gives me the list of patients; how do I get their lists of `assessments`?

Comment: As minimum you should use joins, like in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
 @assessments = Assessment.joins(:patient => {:care_group_assignments => :clinician).where(["clinicians.id = ?", @clinician.id]).order("assessments.created_at desc")
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: returns **ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in Pages#home** `Association named 'clinician' was not found on Patient; perhaps you misspelled it?`